# Is it possible to create an acid anhydride that's stable in water and if so what conditions must its structure satisfy?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

I ask this question because if acid anhydrides are always unstable in water then my interest, as a student of pharmacology, would be greatly diminished. Acid anhydrides are, in my books, at least, the result of a dehydratation reaction between two carboxylic acids and hence their structures look like this:
[image]

Where R1 and R2 are organic substituents.

Comment: Is silica (SiO2) an acid anhydride?

Comment: Nope, acid anhydrides have a minimum of 3 oxygens due to the fact they are composed of two carboxylic acids joined at the OH group with H2O as a by-product of said joining (hence the term anhydride).

Comment: Would you consider [ATP](http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/book/biochemistry/chapt12/bio7.htm)?

Comment: @F'x not in this life time since I see no carboxylic acids in its chemical structure

Comment: [ATP](http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/book/biochemistry/chapt12/bio7.htm) is an anhydride from the phosphoric acid, and sometimes called a “acid anhydride” for this reason… but I left it as a comment, not proposed it as an answer :)

Comment: What you’re interested in is a *carboxylic* anhydride. Acid anhydrides in general are a greater class of compounds that include silica, ATP/ADP and others because they all give acidic hydroxy groups after the addition of water (if slowly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any acid anhydride that has completely stability in water, but I think **the best way to stabilize them would be to choose a cyclic one**, which would therefore favor the anhydride form because it makes a closed ring structure. Looking in that direction, it seems that [phthalic anhydride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phthalic_anhydride) in particular has a  rather slow reaction with water (to the point that solubility values are available!).

[image: phthalic anhydride]

Or, if you want a larger ring, [homophtalic anhydride](http://www.orgsyn.org/orgsyn/orgsyn/prepcontent.asp?prep=cv3p0449) (also [here](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.12274.html)):

[image]

but I don't find any data on its stability/solubility in water.

Comment: Hmm, good idea. Any ideas about an acid anhydride that has a 6-member ring with the carbonyl groups hanging off it? Like sort of like phthalic anhydride but with an extra carbon in the 6-membered ring? I ask because I would imagine, based on the higher stability of 6-membered rings that it might just be even more stable in water.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is years later than the original question, but I add it for anyone who come across it now or in the future...

All acid anhydride and acid chlorides are thermodynamically unstable in water.  They will eventually hydrolyze, but that time could be seconds, minutes, hours, days, or years. Moreover, in the absence of a catalyst, the rate of hydrolysis (kinetics) of any acid anhydride or any acid chloride (carboxylic, phosphoric, sulfonic, etc.) is strongly temperature dependent (hotter = faster, colder = slower, as you would expect).

For example, the classic hydrolysis of acetic anhydride is quite slow until temperatures exceed 55—60 °C.  Similarly, sulfonyl chloride hydrolysis is very slow until temperatures exceed about 70 °C.  This is in part driven by solubility - the substrate needs to be in the same phase as the water for fast rates.  Phosphoric anhydrides such as ATP or ADP can be extremely stable in water at physiological temperatures (37 °C).  The presence of an protic acid, or particularly  a nucleophilic catalyst (hydroxide, amines, thiols), can change the kinetics dramatically.  Thus, you have to pay attention to the temperature, the phasing/solubility, and the identities/properties of the other components in your reaction mixture.

Answer (score 0):

In the inorganic sense of anhydride, carbon dioxide will do.  It forms carbonic acid through the reaction $\ce{CO2 +H2O <=> H2CO3}$, but the equilibrium is strongly on the side of the reactants.  Thereby carbon dioxide is an acid anhydride because it can react with water, but remains predominantly in the anhydride form because that reaction is limited in extent.